# v.kriging Addon not installed - GRASS GIS 7

Tags: grass-gis, installation, extensions, windows-8.1

I am using GRASS GIS 7. When I try to install "v.kriging" module using "g.extension" command, it is not installed. Though it says that the extension is successfully installed, I get the error "'v.kriging' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I then tried to get the code from the following link:

http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/addons/grass-7.0.1RC2/

But all folders in v.kriging.zip are empty.

Can you help me with installing the extension on Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can see the availability status of Addons here:
https://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/  --> Available Add-ons --> List of GRASS GIS 7 Add-ons (build status for Linux and Windows)

Being the GRASS GIS web site admin, I've seen that LAPACK support was missing on the **Linux** build server, now fixed (not relevant for you, though).

Concerning the **winGRASS** side, you need to have the LAPACK and BLAS libraries installed and GRASS GIS compiled with support for it enabled since v.kriging uses matrix functions from those libraries. I suspect that these libraries are also lacking on the winGRASS build server, will contact the admin for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have installed LAPACK and BLAS libraries. Still I get the same error. In this [link](http://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass70/addons/grass-7.0.1/logs/), the status of v.kriging is given as failed. Does it mean that the module will not work on Windows?

Comment: You need to use --with-blas and --with-lapack in the configure step, then compile GRASS GIS on Windows. We plan to ship winGRASS in the near future with LAPACK/BLAS support but this will need some time to update the server...

Comment: Can you please explain in detail on how to compile and install GRASS with blas and lapack. I have downloaded liblapack.dll and libblas.dll for windows. I'm pretty new to GRASS GIS and I have no idea what "--with-blas" and "--with-lapack" means.   Can you please help me with the installation?